# How to echo a message with php having an Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a method for uploading images that checks if the selected file is indeed an image before continuing. If it is not, should show an error somehow. The problem is that the Ajax always executes the `error` function. I've tried to return a `json_encode`, `echo` etc but did not work.

My ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Operations.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
    success: function(data) {
        showAlert(data.res, data.msg);
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = "?c=" + data.plc.toLowerCase();
        }, 1000)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        showAlert("result-error", errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

The php method

```
private function uploadImage($_file)
{
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES[$_file]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
        $path = '../../img/uploads/';
        $file = $path . basename($_FILES[$_file]['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$_file]['tmp_name'], $file);
    } else {
        // What do I do here?
        return json_encode(array(
            'res' => 'result-error',
            'msg' => 'Select an image'
        ));
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd `echo` your `JSON array` then `decode` it using `JavaScript`.

Comment: what error do you see in your console? or network tab...

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to consider before using PHP and AJAX
JSON is an Array structure so you need to make it "beautiful" so that it can be easily read by AJAX functions and also check whether input is done properly so PHP post variables can be retrieved easily

Don't just return the output in JSON, return in as an array.

And for printing the output so like this....

### for php

```
//Set header to JSON so ajax can read it easily
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode(uploadImage($file));//calling the function
```

output given by it can be read by ajax easily